# Can I use the same variable in different positions in dynamic SQL query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am using PostgreSQL to create complexe dynamic queries. In my queries I can use one variable multiple times in multiple positions in the query, to simplify things, I want to know if I can do something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM employees Where name = $1 and id = $2 and manager_id = $2;
```

And then execute the query like this :

```
EXECUTE format ('SELECT * FROM employees Where name = $1 and id = $2 and manager_id = $2;') using (var_name, var_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters are positional, so `$1` always refers to the first parameter regardless where and how often you refer to it.

But you must **not** enclose the parameters in parentheses because that creates an anonymous record. `using (var_name, var_id)` passes a **single** parameter (which is a record with two fields).

So you can use:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM employees Where name = $1 and id = $2 and manager_id = $2') 
 using var_name, var_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @a_horse_with_no_name, this is just an example to explain the issue but I have more complexe queries where I need to use dynamic sql. Do you please know if inversing $1 and $2 still works correctly and $1 still references the first parameter even if it is not in the first position ?

Comment: Yes the numbers are positional. But as written your query only passes a **single** parameter. Do not enclose the list of parameters with parentheses.